# how to make a custom error message with extension method in fluent validation

Tags: fluentvalidation

```
public class Validator : AbstractValidator<Command>
    {
        public Validator(ICheckExists<ICheckEntityExists> checkEntityExists)
        {
                 RuleFor(x => x)
                .EntityDoesNotExist(checkEntityExists, c => new CheckEntityExists()
                {
                    TypeId = c.Id,
                    StatusId = c.StatusId
                });
        }
```

Hi, I Have a problem. The code above generates `"must not exist"` error message.
`EntityDoesNotExist` is an extension method that I can not change.Since it is an extension method I could not use any of this `OverridePropertyName` `WithName` `WithMessage`.

The question is how can I change the error message to a custom one.
I have written this code which does the thing

```
ValidatorOptions.Global.DisplayNameResolver = (type, member, expression) =>
            {
                if (member == null)
                {
                    return "Hello world";
                }
                return member.Name;
            };
```

But it works only if I have 1 rule that has no name and it looks not pretty.
Maybe there it is another way of achieving the same result?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that extension method you are using return an instance of `IRuleBuilder<T, out TProperty>` interface which doesn't contain definitions for method like `WithMessage`. This and other methods you mentioned are extension methods for `IRuleBuilderOptions<T, TProperty>` interface which inherits `IRuleBuilder<T, out TProperty>`.

So one of possible solutions is to wrap `EntityDoesNotExist` extension method into another method which will downcast the returned type to `IRuleBuilderOptions<T, TProperty>`

For example we have class called `Person`:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

Extension method for Name property which returns `IRuleBuilder` type:

```
public static IRuleBuilder<T, string> ValidateNameLength<T>(this IRuleBuilder<T, string> ruleBuilder)
{
   return ruleBuilder.Must(name => name.Length < 5).WithMessage("Incorrect length");
}
```

So we can wrap this method something like this:

```
    public static IRuleBuilderOptions<T, string> ValidateNameLengthWrapper<T>(this IRuleBuilder<T, string> ruleBuilder)
    {
        return (IRuleBuilderOptions<T, string>) ruleBuilder.ValidateNameLength();
    }
```

Then we can use `WithMessage` method to override error description:

```
public class Validator : AbstractValidator<Person>
{
    public Validator()
    {
        CascadeMode = CascadeMode.Continue;
        RuleFor(x => x.Name!).ValidateNameLengthWrapper().WithMessage("Name must be less than 5 characters");
    }
}
```

But maybe would be better to write your own extension method or resolve the problem outside the validation context.